# CUDA: Unable to copy character array from host to unified device memory using cudaMemcpyToSymbol

Tags: cuda

I am pretty new to Cuda programming. I am trying to copy a character array from host to unified device memory. The code does not throw any error but shows the device's memory as blank lines.

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int i = 0, n = 0;
    unsigned char * buff;
    char inp[512] = "abc";
    n = 10;

    while (i < n)
    {
         int num = i, size = 0;
         while(num > 0)
         {
             ++size;
             num /= 10;
         }
         size += strlen(inp);
         num = i;
         inp[size--] = '\0';
         while(num > 0)
         {
              inp[size--] = '0' + num%10;
              num /= 10;
         }
         size = strlen(inp);
         cudaMallocManaged(&buff, (size+1)*sizeof(char));
         cudaMemcpyToSymbol(buff, &inp, sizeof(inp), 0, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
         printf("%s\n", inp);
         printf("%s\n", buff);
    }

    cudaDeviceReset();
    return 0;
 }
```

This is the output of the above code:

```
abc

abc1

abc12

abc123

abc1234

abc12345

abc123456

abc1234567

abc12345678

abc123456789
```

Please help me out.

Comment: buff isn't a device symbol and cudaMemcpyToSymbol isn't required in this case at all given you are using managed memory

Comment: So for this, do I need to make buff a device symbol?

Comment: No. You need to completely forget about device symbols in this context. They are something completely unrelated to what you are trying to do in this case

Comment: Thanks a lot. Using memcpy instead of cudaMemcpyToSymbol solved the issue.

Comment: Would you like to write a short answer detailing your solution for the next person. I will happily upvote it. Then this question can be marked (by you) as answered by accepting the answer a couple of days after you add it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here, the buff is allocated in the unified memory and is not a device symbol. Hence, in this context, we need to forget about device symbols.
Data in Unified memory can be accessed directly by the host as well as device as and when required. The device automatically fetches the desired data from unified memory without the need to explicitly moving data to the device memory.

The problem here can be solved by using memcpy instead of cudaMemcpyToSymbol. cudaMemcpyToSymbol is used to write data in device memory and not the unified memory.

```
cudaMemcpyToSymbol(buff, &inp, sizeof(inp), 0, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
```

should be replaced with

```
memcpy(buff, inp, size+1);
```

Thanks @talonmies for the suggestion.